# Oracle Auditing for normal accounts/users

Tags: oracle, ddl, dml, auditing

In Oracle 10g, the command "audit all" does not enable the auditing for normal users.  Customers requries auditing activities for all the accounts that they login.  Works only with SysDBA and SysOper permission.

Thank you
Sam Roberts

Comment: Is there a question you want to ask.Did you look at auditing documentation and have you tried some code. What in your code does not work?

Comment: What kind of activities you want to audit for normal users? What do you mean by does not enable auditing? Show us what have you set to `audit_trail` parameter and the command that you have used for enabling auditing for the normal user.

Comment: We have used "audit all" command.  We found that the create, delete, modify tables - does not reflected in the logs, done by normal operators.  However, we get all the logs for sysdba and sysoper privileged users. We require the following details:
Queries :
** Command for audit based on individual user,ddl,dml commands 
(on unix and windows build )
** Command for disable audit based on individual user,ddl,dml commands
** How to give privilege based ddl and dml commands

Comment: We did not get an update on the above queries.  Please help us to resolve the above issues.  Else, des it needs to be considered as a feature request for Oracle auditing?